# Asking for forgivness

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, islamic-philosophy, hanafi, islamic-basis

It seems that if a muslim sins, he should ask for forgiveness as Allah is the most forgiving.

My question is, if you commit a sin and ask for forgiveness once, is that enough, or should you ask for forgiveness for that sin for the rest of your life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to ask for forgiveness for that sin for the rest of the life, but one thing we have to keep in mind that that sin is not repeated again and our repentance should be 
whole hearted. InshaAllah , Allah will forgive us even if it is one time rather than asking for forgiveness often.

http://harunyahya.com/en/Articles/17230/verses-of-the-qur%E2%80%99an-about

http://www.alquranclasses.com/quran-forgivness/